# SingleTop launchMode fails when app is opened from notification or external Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, notifications

I have this minimized app:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
    }

}
```

**ActivityB.java**

```
public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ActivityB"
            android:exported="false"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
```

**1)** I launch a notification from a Service with the app closed (killed) using TaskStackBuilder to  open MainActivity -> ActivityB in the stack just as documentation says (https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation) :

```
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
...
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "1")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText("Message")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        android.app.Notification buildNotification = mBuilder.build();
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotifyMgr.notify(1, buildNotification);
```

ActivityB is opened on notification click but using back button doesn't go to parent Activity (MainActivity) which is precisely what you want with TaskStackBuilder. It gets the app closed.

**2)** When the app with MainActivity opened is in background (home button), if I share an audio file from another app to the app, onCreate is always called instead of onNewIntent. Looking at the documentation of launchMode, shouldn't it call to onNewIntent as MainActivity is singleTop and is in the top of the stack?

**Tested in**

- Android 10 & Android 11
- compileSdkVersion 32
- targetSdkVersion 32

Answer (score 0):

Try singleInstance, seems like there is another stack open otherwise the system would indeed call onNewIntent instead of onCreate.

Comment: singleInstance doesn't allow two activities to be in the same task, so if you have two different activities A (singleInstance) -> B and you push the home button, when you return there is only A